# How to create nested form in django?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

In a django project, I have a book form class and an author form class.

```
from django import forms
class BookForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    isbn_no = forms.IntegerField(max_value=9999999999999)
    publish_date = forms.DateField()

class AuthorForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    birth_date = forms.DateField()
```

As a writer may have more than one book, I want to create an array of BookForm and add it to AuthorForm as BookList. How can I do that?
NB: These forms are not model form.

Answer (score 1):

```
Some= inlineformset_factory(models.AuthorForm, models.BookForm, extra=4)
```

Comment: AuthorForm and BookForm are not model form.